# How to set a seaborn swarmplot size and change legend location?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

I'm trying to plot a swarmplot with seaborn but I'm struggling with the legend of the plot, I managed to change its position if the figure, but now it is cropped and no information is shown:

[image]

I moved the legend with:

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

I changed the size of the figure with no luck

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
```

I also tried `tight_layout()` but it just removes the legend from the plot.

Any ideas on how to make it appear on the side of the plot nicely without any cropping on the side or bottom?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legend is not taken into account when `plt.tight_layout()` tries to optimize the spaces. However you can set the spaces manually using
[`plt.subplots_adjust()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust)

The relevant argument here is the `right` side of the figure, so `plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)` would be a good start. `0.7` means that the right part of the axes is at 70% of the total figure size, which should give you enough space for the legend.
Then, you may want to change that number according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this.

```
# Import necessary libraries
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize Figure and Axes object
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))

# Load in the data
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

# Create swarmplot
sns.swarmplot(x="species", y="petal_length", data=iris, ax=ax)

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

[Result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiQXt.png)

[Source](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/seaborn-python-tutorial#figsize)

(its too late maybe i know but i wanted to share i found already)